React Native 0.68.7 > 0.69.12 - Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
I upgraded the React Native version from 0.68.7 to 0.69.12 and I followed the React Native Version Upgrade exactly.
After completing the update, I cleaned node_modules and pods with their caches. I also cleaned the build folder with XCode.
While building the application, I get the following error for App Registration;

Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialisation error when loading React Native.
Although I tried many solutions from many sources, I still could not solve the problem
package.json :
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "mobx": "^6.9.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.6.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.12",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^5.5.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.8.24",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "3.6.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.12",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.10.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.6.2",
    "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  }

index.js :
/**
 * @format
 */

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

App.js :
import React from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import Store from "./src/store/index";
import Router from "./src/Router";
import NavigationService from "./src/configs/NavigationService";

const App = () => {

  return (<Provider {...Store}>
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Router ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
      }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Provider>);
};
export default App;

Router.js :
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

// Authenticate
import Login from "../src/screens/Authenticate/Login";
import ResetPassword from "../src/screens/Authenticate/ResetPassword";

// Loading
import Loading from "../src/screens/Loading/Index";

// Home
import HomeIndex from "../src/screens/Home/Index";
import Commissioning from "./screens/Commissioning/Index";

const AuthenticateStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  ResetPassword: {
    screen: ResetPassword,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  }
  // some other screens
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeIndex,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  Commissioning: {
    screen: Commissioning,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  }
  // some other screens
});

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Loading,
  App: HomeStack,
  Auth: AuthenticateStack,
}, {
  initialRouteName: "Loading",
});

export default createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

NavigationService.js :
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};

I'm stuck. Can anyone help me?, Thanks
